# How do you get a response from a Flask app with curl?

Tags: api, flask, allennlp

I'm building a Flask test predictor using AllenNLP.

I'm passing 'passage' and 'question' from a .json file to the predictor.

However, when I pass the json file using curl, it doesn't return a response.  Is there a special return in Flask to get it?

Code looks like:

```
 from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor as AllenNLPPredictor


from flask import Flask
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def hello():
    return "<h1>Test app!</h1>"


class PythonPredictor:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.predictor = AllenNLPPredictor.from_path(
            "https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/bidaf-elmo-model-2018.11.30-charpad.tar.gz"
        )

    def predict(self, payload):
        if request.method == "POST":
            prediction = self.predictor.predict(
                passage=payload["passage"], question=payload["question"]
            )
            return prediction["best_span_str"]
```

Curl command looks like:
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @sample.json

Comment: Looks like an incorrect URL.  Can you try `http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict`

Comment: Thanks for that catch.  That was just a typo in my curl as I was trying a different route.  I've edited it above now.  If you look at the route now, everything is under "/".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood (I'm guessing you're asking how to obtain the JSON submission in your route, and return the result) it sounds like you need to do something like:

```
p = PythonPredictor()

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    data = request.get_json()
    result = p.predict(data)
    return result
```

This effectively runs the data in your `sample.json` through your `PythonPredictor.predict` method, and returns that prediction to the client.

Notice this code creates the instance `p` outside the route function, so that the NLP model is only loaded when your flask app starts (not on every request).  However it looks like this may re-download that file, unless `AllenNLPPredictor.from_path` does some caching, so it would probably be advisable to manually download that file to your own storage first, and load from there in the `PythonPredictor.__init__` function.

Let me know if any of this needs clarification, or I've missunderstood.

Comment: Thanks so much @v25.  That was precisely it. I think overall I was missing a concept here that your code snippet provided. To load the model in the PythonPredictor init do you have a link that I can study how to load it from my own server (azure hosted)?

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much for sharing your views. It's gonna help me alot as well